# Apache Webserver stopped working on windows7

Tags: php, windows, apache, webserver

I have an Apache 2.4.9 web-server running php5 on windows7. It had been working fine, but now it isn't running. I see nothing about php in the application logs, nor in the Apache logs.

I do not know how to troubleshoot php5 in windows. I cannot run any phpinfo(); scripts, but I can see where php is started in the Apache logs

```
[Mon May 12 17:26:49.832429 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1388:tid 528] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I see no notice of PHP crashing though. 
The page is http://rm362c.umecheme.maine.edu/
and you can see the php in the source now.

what steps can I take to troubleshoot and debug php5 as it pertains to Apache2.4 and Windows7?

Comment: *"and you can see the php in the source now."* - HTML source, yes. PHP source, no.

Comment: i think thats the problem @Fred-ii-, he can see the php script now, as php is borked

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP source, *yes*.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood then. @Dagon my bad. I didn't open the site, that's why.

Comment: very bad, spanky time for you!

Comment: @Dagon Duh....... ok I see it now. "Source IN source".

Comment: A long shot... the source starts with `?php`. Is it by chance missing the opening `<` as in `<?php`

Comment: No, the php scripts are correctly formatted. They had been functional but now the server is borked and I don't know why.

Comment: FYI your PHP code is **horribly** insecure. You're `exec()`ing user input directly. A malicious user could do very bad things to your server.

Comment: ok, how do I fix that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Put <?php phpinfo(); ?> into a file with an extension of .php and see if it executes, if not your apache/php configuration needs to be redone if it does you may simply have an issue with your PHP.

I can't see your apparent "horribly insecure" code as the site you've referenced is down but if it is you may want to look at compromised apache modules, odd configuration changes, etc. as a possible cause.

Answer (score 3):

Add below lines to php.ini to view any php error in your browser --
`error_reporting = -1`
`display_errors = On`
Remove above lines in your production environment (Source: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#89648 ). 

For more check http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php .

Answer (score 1):

If port 80 is blocked by Skype or some other applications you will not be able to run apache since http requires port 80 and https require port 443 open. or if you have IIS web server running it also could be reason.

Please go through below article for further details if its xampp on windows7

http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-troubleshoot-xampp-apache-not-running-on-windows-7/